# How to avoid errors when casting null REST data to datetime

Tags: rest, powershell, foreach, properties

I am using a REST API to pull invoice data, from an external company, into an Excel file using PowerShell. I can pull the data just fine using the Invoke-RestMethod. Although, when it pulls the datetime fields, it is in a format I do not prefer. To automate my job as much as possible, is there a way to cast the data to datetime. Keep in mind, not every field has data so there are null fields which cause the errors. I basically want to pull all data, if it has an ugly-formatted datetime, change it to the way I want to see it, or if it is empty, just continue on.

I have tried [nullable[datetime]] (found it on google somewhere), but that throws other errors. I have tried using an 'IF' but that also generates in out set of syntax errors.

```
$out = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $assetsURL
#$out.Invoices | Export-Excel $outputcsv
$out.Invoices |
    Select-Object * |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Properties = [ordered]@{
        InvoiceNumber = $_.InvoiceNumber
        DueDate = $_.DueDate #[datetime]::parseexact($_.DueDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
        Currency = $_.Currency
        TotalDue = $_.TotalDue
        PeriodFrom = $_.PeriodFrom #[datetime]::parseexact($_.PeriodFrom,'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
        PeriodTo = $_.PeriodTo #[datetime]::parseexact($_.PeriodTo,'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
        BillingName = $_.BillingName
        BillingAddress = $_.BillingAddress
        BillingAttentionTo = $_.BillingAttentionTo
        BillingCity = $_.BillingCity
        BillingState = $_.BillingState
        BillingPostalCode = $_.BillingPostalCode
        RemitToName = $_.RemitToName
        RemitToAddress = $_.RemitToAddress
        RemitToAttentionTo = $_.RemitToAttentionTo
        RemitToCity = $_.RemitToCity
        RemitToState = $_.RemitToState
        RemitToPostalCode = $_.RemitToPostalCode
        Lease = $_.Lease
        Schedule = $_.Schedule
        CreatedDate = $_.CreatedDate #[datetime]::parseexact($_.CreatedDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss',    $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
        }
    New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
 } | Export-Excel $outputcsv
```

Just updating because I may not have been clear on what the issue is. In the columns 'DueDate', 'PeriodFrom', 'PeriodTo', and 'CreatedDate', these are all pulled from the REST API. 'DueDate' and 'CreatedDate' seem to be properly populated but 'PeriodFrom' and 'PeriodTo' may or may not have a date.

Currently, without any trickery, the date (if it exists) returns as:

```
2019-09-05T00:00:00
```

I would like to return an empty field if it does not exist or return the date in the like the following if it does exit:

```
2019-09-05
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TryParseExact`:

```
ForEach-Object {
    $parsedDate = [datetime]::MinValue
    $Properties = [ordered]@{ # remove the CreatedDate from the HashTable
    [...]

if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($_.CreatedDate,'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss',
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,[ref]$ParsedDate)) 
{$Properties.Add("CreatedDate", $parsedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))}
}

else {
$Properties.Add("CreatedDate",$null)
}
```

Note that you can add array of string formats instead of a single string, for example:

```
[String[]]$DateStrings = "M/dd/yyyy h:mmtt","M/d/yyyy h:mmtt","MM/d/yyyy h:mmtt"
```

Then it would be:

```
[datetime]::TryParseExact($_.CreatedDate,$DateStrings...)
```

Comment: I see what you did there, but I think that is where I am having the issue. As soon as I put an 'if' inside the foreach loop, I get a syntax warning that I am missing the '=' operator after the 'if'

Comment: 24hour format is upper case `HH` any hour greater 11 will error out.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I could never get it working properly, so I just left the time format as the ugly format for now due to work time constraints. If I ever get a chance, I can come back to this. Thanks again.